# Using keyListeners with multiple threads / KeyBinding

Tags: java, multithreading, keylistener

I'm trying to make an insanely simple game, but it still may need to take around 8 keys at once.

Using keyListener, I can take around 3-4 with some delays, which I don't want.

I have no idea how to use keyBinding, which I assume would solve my issue. (Please don't just put this link, I've looked at it as well as other sources: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

My first guess was to add threads to a keyListener, but I have no idea how to do that, and looking it up gave me no decent answer.

```
private void makeKeyListeners() {
    f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            switch (key) {. . .}
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            switch (key) {. . .}
        }
    });
}
```

Using this, I don't get enough input (can't detect 8 keys pressed down at the same time)

So my big question is; How can I take input from 8+ keys at once?

If the best way to solve this is with keyBindings, could you do me a favor and explain them in depth?

Comment: It's inconceivable to me that the above code doesn't record all eight key presses.  We'll probably need to see the rest of the code, and provide some output too that shows why you think there aren't multiple key presses.  (P.S. Swing is not thread safe, so you can't solve this with multiple threads.  Mult-ithreading for a game is tricky, and the user input should probably be done one one thread anyway.)

Comment: *”My first guess was to add threads to a keyListener,”* Well, that’s a bad idea, as Swing is single threaded and the event would delivered on the event dispatching thread. I’d encourage the use of key bindings, as it solves one of the primary issues with `KeyListener` - that of focus. Assuming you don’t need all the keys active at the same time, I’d use a Set, which defines which keys are actively pressed and the allow the games “main loop” to simply inspect this to determine what actions need to be taken

Comment: *”can't detect 8 keys pressed down at the same time”* this isn’t an issue with Swing, but a limitation on the hardware

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://blog.controlspace.org/2010/08/n-key-rollover-what-it-is-and-how-to.html?m=1) and fig a little deeper into how keyboards and drivers work

Comment: And [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses) for more details

Comment: Yes, that is the issue. Marking the question as complete now. Or not, can't mark my own question as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a hardware issue. I went to http://blog.controlspace.org/2010/08/n-key-rollover-what-it-is-and-how-to.html?m=1 (MadProgrammer's comment) and tested 3 different keyboard I own, and they all perform differently.